# how to get whole content of Web View to generate PDF file in android?

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio, android-webview

I'm Currently attempting to include a PDF export feature for my Android Application.

This involves populating a Url, putting that into a WebView, then writing the contents of that WebView to a PDF using adapted code from here:

public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

```
public void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
            deleteRecursive(child);
    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}

public void bmpToPdfMail(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String GVCode = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + "_InvoiceTest");
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Invoices");
    if (myDir.exists()) {
        deleteRecursive(myDir);
    }
    myDir.mkdirs();

    String fname = GVCode + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) {
        deleteRecursive(file);
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Document document = new Document();
    String input = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Invoices/" + GVCode + ".jpg";
    String output = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Invoices/" + GVCode + ".pdf";
    String stringPrintDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Invoices/";
    File myDirPdf = new File(stringPrintDirectory);
    if (!myDirPdf.exists()) {
        myDirPdf.mkdirs();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
        writer.open();
        document.open();
        Image img = Image.getInstance(input);
        document.setPageSize(img);
        document.newPage();
        img.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        document.add(img);
        document.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How to create PDF from WebView, which is hidden part?

However when the PDF is generated, I am only getting the visible area of the 
WebView, so information off-screen is being cut off.

How to get Whole Content like (Visible or not Visible Part) in WebView to export PDF File From My Android Application...?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get bitmap, after the page is loaded successfully.

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(WebView v) {
    Picture picture = v.capturePicture();
    Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(),
    picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas( b );

    picture.draw( c );
    return b;
}
```

Since, `capturePicture()` is deprecated in api level 19, Use

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(WebView v) {
    float scale = v.getScale(); // Used to capture whole the content
    int webViewHeight = (int)(v.getContentHeight() * scale);
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), webViewHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    v.draw(canvas);
    return image;
}
```

Use bitmap to generate PDF. Before that, try to view bitmap to make sure if there is a problem with pdf generation code.

Comment: I try this Method But Not getting a Proper Bitmap File

Comment: So, are all the content included in bitmap?

Comment: No, I getting a only Visible Part and Other part is blank printed

Comment: Use `onDraw()` method of webview instead, edited my answer.

Comment: I am not getting your answer properly. Can you please provide me some insight? What to do in onDraw() method of webview? Waiting for your response.

Comment: You have to manipulate `onDraw()` method of webview in order to capture whole content of webview. We are using  `webView.draw(canvas);`

Comment: Where can I implement onDraw Method? As I am seeing webview.onDrawForeground(); only in WebView Class. Please provide me more details on this.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the point. My bad, I did not formatted the code, edited one. look at the snippet now.

Comment: is above code working? getscale method is also deprecated ?

Comment: You can use `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density` instead of `getScale()`.

Comment: @PareshP. can you help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870164/convert-html-into-pdf-using-webview-not-display-full-content-with-images

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not so elegant but working:

```
    wb.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    wb.layout(0, 0, wb.getMeasuredWidth(), wb.getMeasuredHeight());
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    int pageNumber = 1;
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(wb.getMeasuredWidth(),
            wb.getMeasuredHeight(), pageNumber).create();
    PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
    //wb.draw(page.getCanvas());
    wb.draw(page.getCanvas());
    document.finishPage(page);
```

This creates a PDF page as wide as necessary to fit the whole WebView.
Hope this help!