# How do I turn all of a webview content into a bitmap?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, bitmap, height

My app generates large text strings, I want to be able to allow a user to output them as an image should they choose.

I use a webview to display the string as that allows to embed anchors, deal with new lines inside a long string and display it all in a very neat easy way.

Before I simply took the webview and converted it to a bitmap. This worked great but now no longer works. I am open to alternative ways to achieve my goal (I am a hobby developer of a free app though so I apologise if I am missing something blatant)

The old code saved the complete content of the webview including content outside off the screen. The new code (despite being near on Identical does not). The issue seems to be that the height of the webview is not reported correctly (if i add to the height then it works, but since I do not know the size of the string I can not always predict the height *see below)

I tried PixelShot library this presented the same problem.
I tried adding to the height of the webview when calculating the height of the bitmap...this showed progress but is not a good work around as we do not know the height of the block of text. (font height x every 
 sounded good but some sentences are long and thus the height would get cut off)
I tried using the old method exactly but some of the code is depreciated
I have tried encasing the webview in a scrollview

```
    fun displayResults(input:String){

        var visabilityBackground = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean("webPageVis",false)
        if (visabilityBackground) {generator_webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE) }else{generator_webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)}
        generator_webview.loadUrl("about:blank")
        generator_webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled
        generator_webview.loadUrl("about:blank")
        var output=input
            .replace("/n","<br>")
        lastweb=input
            .replace("/n",System.lineSeparator()) // not working....arghhh todo fix later or threaten ide with deletion
        generator_webview.loadData(output,"text/html", "UTF-8")
        Log.d("height","height : "+generator_webview.height)
        Log.d("height","height measured : "+generator_webview.measuredHeight)
        Log.d("height","height content: "+generator_webview.contentHeight)
        Log.d("height","height scroll: "+generator_webview.scrollView().height)
        Log.d("height","height min: "+generator_webview.minimumHeight)
        Log.d("height","height s: "+generator_scrollview.height)
        Log.d("height","height s measured: "+generator_scrollview.measuredHeight)
        Log.d("height","height s min: "+generator_scrollview.minimumHeight)
    }
```

The results of the height logs are always the following:

```
height: height : 2116
height: height measured : 2116
height: height content: 605
height: height scroll: 0
height: height min: 0
height: height s: 2116
height: height s measured: 2116
height: height s min: 0
```

This is regardless of the generated content being one line or 2 pages/screens of content.

(the webview is currently incased in a scroll view as I read that would fix the issue....it did not)

The code to make the bitmap is currently :

```
    fun screenshot (webView:WebView):Bitmap?{

        try {
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.width, webView.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            canvas.drawColor(-0x1)
            webView.draw(canvas)
            return bitmap
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }
```

This is called elsewhere, passing on the webview id
webView.measuredHeight .contentHeight

The webview is created with :

```
     <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/generator_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/generator_adView" 
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp" 
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

   app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/generator_button_generate"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">
    <WebView

            android:id="@+id/generator_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
            android:saveEnabled="true">
    </WebView>
    </ScrollView>
```

I have also tried it not incased in the scrollview (with its height and width set to 0dp as it expands to fit the space...as per the new guidelines)

The expect result is a bitmap that has the full content of the view including what is outside of the screen. 
It is 100% an issue with the height not getting reported correctly (I am using WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw() so the full view is rendered (as shown when i added to the height and was able to save a taller image bitmap with more of the content shown...It is being rendered the bitmap just is not getting the correct height.

I have been at this for 3 days and I just can not figure it out

Answer (score 1):

```
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.width,webView.height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
webView.draw(canvas)
bitmap // Use Your Bitmap Here
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, the solution was to put the webview inside a `ScrollView` as you mentioned in your question, maybe there is something different in `layout_height` below.

Here is the view XML that solved our problem:

```
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">
            <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </WebView>
       </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

I actually found a solution in the related links on the side.....seems more of a work around than a solution but it works so I am happy

```
fun screenshot (webView:WebView):Bitmap?{
webView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
webView.layout(0, 0, webView.measuredWidth, webView.measuredHeight)

try {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.width, webView.measuredHeight, 
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(-0x1)
    webView.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
return null
}
```

This was from [how to get whole content of Web View to generate PDF file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321884/how-to-get-whole-content-of-web-view-to-generate-pdf-file-in-android?rq=1)

and the change means the code now works.

Comment: Not working, same like capturePicture just convert what displayed on screen not full webview..!